# How to plot a half pie chart in Jqplot

Tags: php, jquery, charts, jqplot

I  have a form something like this

```
<form>
<table>
<tr><th colspan="2">Table1 Content</th></tr>
<tr><td><div align="left">International Services</div></td><td><input type="text" name="expenditure[]"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><div align="left">Public sector debt interest</div></td><td><input type="text" name="expenditure[]"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><div align="left">Defence</div></td><td><input type="text" name="expenditure[]"/></td></tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
        <th colspan="2">
         Table2 content
        </th></tr>
      <tr><td><div align="left">VAT</div></td><td><input type="text" name="revenue[]"/></td></tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div align="left">Other taxes, royalties & adjustments</div></td><td><input type="text" name="revenue[]"/></td></tr>

      <tr>
        <td><div align="left">Interest and dividends</div></td><td><input type="text" name="revenue[]"/></td></tr>
      <tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The user will input numbers into the different text box , I have to plot a pie chart using JqPlot where half of the pie chart should show table 1 content and the other half will show table2 content

The basic script for Jqplot is as follow

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = [
    ['Heavy Industry', <?php echo $_POST['q_1']?>],['Retail',<?php echo $_POST['q_2']?>], ['Light Industry', <?php echo $_POST['q_3']?>],
    ['Out of home', <?php echo $_POST['q_4']?>],
  ];
  var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', [data],
    {
      seriesDefaults: {
        // Make this a pie chart.
        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
          // Put data labels on the pie slices.
          // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
          showDataLabels: true
        }
      },
      legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

Can any one help me out with this

I just want to know how i will use the values to plot in 180 degree chart instead of 360 degree

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check this out,

its a kind of hacked solution but should get you the expected result of plotting a half pie chart

```
startAngle: 180
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/96vog3h1/5/**